# Number of ways to empty three boxes in a given number of steps, while taking at most one ball from each box at every step

Tags: combinatorics

Given a set of three boxes, each of which contains number of balls (say $x,y,z$ respectively), we have to empty the all the three boxes in exactly $N$ steps.

At each step we have to pick at least $1$ ball from any of the three boxes and once we pick a ball from a box we can not pick another ball from the same box in same turn (so at most we can pick three balls in each step and at least 1 ball).

So, given $x,y,z$ and $N$, we have to tell how many ways we can empty all the three boxes. Sorry this seems to be an easy one but my combinatorics is poor. Please suggest me how to proceed
EDIT:the balls in each box are same (i.e. not distinguishable!)

Comment: Are the balls distinguishible?

Comment: A quick glance tells me it might be harder than it looks...  If I were allowed to pick *no* balls on a turn, it would be, simply, $\ _nC_x \times \ _nC_y \times \ _nC_z$, but that has a possibility of creating answers with empty turns.

Comment: no they all are same..but I wonder does it matter...

Comment: @DanUznanski But if you had empty turns, you could generate infinitely many ways by having any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ empty turns between real turns. Which wouldn't be very interesting to be honest. Edit: the asker has specified that $1\leq \text{number of balls picked}\leq3$.

Comment: @EulCan The impression I got was that you had an exact time limit of $n$ turns.

Comment: @DanUznanski Upon re-reading the question, I realised that at least $1$ ball must be picked each turn so the point was invalid anyway.

Comment: Note that another key point of information is missing: can we distinguish the balls? If one is labelled $x_{1}$ and another $x_{2}$, then drawing $x_{1}$ followed by $x_{2}$ in the next step would be distinct from drawing $x_{2}$, then $x_{1}$. Please clarify the problem.

Comment: as i said earlier comments ..they all are same ..

Comment: @ChrisK I think k_12John assumed you meant "are the balls [e.g. an arbitrary $x$ & $y$] distinguishable" with your previous comment. That's how it seemed to me. But the question is laid out quite vaguely so this would need to be clarified.

Comment: only the balls in different boxes are distinguishable ...the balls in same box are not distinguishable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a function $f(x,y,z,n)$ with the following rules: $f(0,0,0,0)=1$ (empty urns with no time left is fine), $f(x,y,z, n < \max(x,y,z))=0$ (more balls in an urn than turns left is bad, we'd never be able to empty it in time), and the main one that tells us how we can remove balls: $$f(x,y,z,n)=f(x-1,y,z,n-1)+f(x,y-1,z,n-1)+f(x,y,z-1,n-1)+f(x-1,y-1,z,n-1)+f(x-1,y,z-1,n-1)+f(x,y-1,z-1,n-1)+f(x-1,y-1,z-1,n-1)$$ 
This is amenable to dynamic programming, but not pretty. You might get mileage out of the fact that x, y, and z are basically interchangeable: $f(x,y,z,n)=f(\min(x,y,z),\text{med}(x,y,z),\max(x,y,z),n)$, where med is the "median" function, so we can sort $x$, $y$, and $z$ and come up with the same answer.

EDIT: one more constraint to make life easier: if $n > x+y+z$, $f(x,y,z,n) = 0$ (if there's more turns than balls *total*, then we'll run out of balls before we run out of turns and that's bad)

Comment: can u plz explain whats your logic..??

Comment: You lost me at $f(x,y,z,n<\max(x,y,z))$; I'd be grateful if you could explain how you derived the parameters for $f$. Thanks.

Comment: f(x,y,z,n<max(x,y,z)) this seems to be clear as if N>max(a,b,c) ..f(x,y,z,N)=0.am i right..? @ Dan Uzanaski..??

Comment: $f$ has parameters:  $x$ $y$ and $z$ are the number of balls in each urn; $n$ is the number of turns remaining.  Obviously, if one of the urns has more balls than there are remaining turns, you cannot possibly empty that urn, so there's 0 ways to complete the task.  The others are -- clearly a empty urns with no turns left means you've won; and a giant terrible recursive equation that describes the 7 states you can get to from any given state.

Comment: @DanUznanski Thanks for explaining. I'd got a similar result but wanted to understand your notation. I don't think this problem is easily solvable. Not right now, anyway.